# databricks: truncate table in redshift

Tags: amazon-redshift, databricks

I want to delete redshift table within databricks notebook. I can query the table but when I try to delete it, I get an error message.

```
truncate_traffic_sql = "TRUNCATE TABLE my_table"
spark.read \
  .format("com.databricks.spark.redshift") \
  .option("url", f"jdbc:postgresql://fw-rs-qa.xxxxx.us-east-1.redshift.amazonaws.com:5439/mydb?user={credentials['user']}&password={credentials['password']}") \
  .option("query", truncate_traffic_sql) \
  .option("tempdir", "s3a://my-bucket/Fish/tmp") \
  .option("forward_spark_s3_credentials", "true") \
  .load()
```

> Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Exception thrown in awaitResult:

> org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "TABLE"

Comment: can you try `TRUNCATE my_table` ?

Comment: when I run TRUNCATE my_table, I get "Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near ". error message.